# Problem with save Qty for Item's Status to Become Out of Stock

Tags: order-status, form-validation, qty-increment

I'm running a Magento Shop version 1.7 and have a problem with saving qty for an item's status to become "Out of Stock" from 0 to 2.

When I click on the button "save config", the browser is loading and loading a few minutes and when its finish I receive the message that the new config is saved - but when I check it again, the qty for Item's Status to Become Out of Stock number is not changed to 2 :(

Whats wrong? It is a bug?

Comment: Alex,are you taking about product or sales item???Also you taking about when you have changing  then qty it not change,am i right?

Comment: If you're using flat product tables, does reindexing catalog_product_flat fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you have "Qty for Item's Status to Become Out of Stock" set to 2 under System > Configuration > Catalog > Inventory > Product stock options. Is that the case? If so set it to 0 and they should only then be marked as out of stock when the qty is 0.

[image: Image showing field]

Comment: yeah you right. System > Configuration > Catalog > Inventory > Product stock options. <-- when im setting it to 2 and click save config, the browser is loading and loading. And when it is finish it's tell me the config is saving. But know, when im going again to the option Product stock options, the Number is always 0 :( can you help me?

Comment: "But know, when im going again to the option Product stock options, the Number is always 0 :(". Do you mean when you go back to a product the qty is still set as 0?

I think your expecting it to change all the products to qty of 2 which this WILL NOT do, this will only set the "Out Of Stock/In Stock" based on if the product has 2 or less in stock. If you want to update all products to have 2 in stock you need to use the mass update on the Catalog > Manage Products page. Select All and then select Update attribute from the action dropdown. Then on the next page you can change the QTY.